# Conditonal rendering REACT modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a view modal component (ViewModal.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Modal.css';

class ViewModal extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    handleModalShowHide() {
        this.setState({ showHide: !this.state.showHide })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                    Write a review
                </Button>

                <Modal show={this.state.showHide}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                        <Modal.Title>Add your review</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        ModalBody
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Close
                    </Button>
                        <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Save Review
                    </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default ViewModal;
```

I import this in another functional component called viewcard.js
The logic of viewcard.js is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import ViewModal from './ViewModal';
import Card from 'Card';

function handleClick(){
    console.log('in handle');
 }
const viewcard = () => {
    return ( 
        <p onClick={() => handleClick()}/>
         Some text in paragraph
        </p>
     );
}

export default viewcard;
```

The Card component displays some text on the screen. 
What I am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on that text, I want to show the modal.

Currently If I render the modal inside viewcard, by calling it, It will show a button based on this line of logic

```
                <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                    Write a review
                </Button>
```

I want to remove the button and have the same behaviour happen when the user clicks on the text in viewcard.js

Comment: please add `Card` code to your question..

Comment: @HagaiHarari - The card was just a placeholder, I have changed that to a paragraph now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewCard component:-

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ViewModal from './ViewModal';
import Card from 'Card';

const ViewCard = () => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    function handleClick(){
       setShowModal(!showModal)
    }

    return ( 
        <Card onClick={() => handleClick()}/>
        {showModal && <ViewModal hideBtn={true} showModal={true} />}
     );
}

export default ViewCard;
```

ViewModal Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Modal.css';

class ViewModal extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
           showHide: this.props.showModal ? true : false
        }
    }

    handleModalShowHide() {
        this.setState({ showHide: !this.state.showHide })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.hideBtn ? null : <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                    Write a review
                </Button>}

                <Modal show={this.state.showHide}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                        <Modal.Title>Add your review</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        ModalBody
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Close
                    </Button>
                        <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => this.handleModalShowHide()}>
                            Save Review
                    </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default ViewModal;
```

But you should always create a separate modal component.

Comment: thanks for this @shubham-chitransh I will give this a try and let you know how that goes, thanks a ton.

Comment: tried that but got this error 
```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined
new ViewModal
src/Containers/MainBody/Listing/ViewModal.js:11
```
its 3:20am here , so off to sleep, will try this tomorrow.

Comment: I had to modify your ViewModal.js logic a little bit and have the  
```
showHide: this.props.showModal ? true : false
`` 
in componentDidmount().

Comment: what did you mean by this "But you should always create a separate modal component."

Comment: That means that your Modal component should be separate and it shouldn't contain anything else, so that you don't need to show/hide that content conditionally.